# C++ MSVC dll compiling error missing type specifier and redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, compiler-errors

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 and im compiling a dll. I want to call the function InitPreySplitPipe i have already tried calling it with ::pr::InitPreySplitPipe and i copied the interprocess.cpp code into game_local.cpp and interprocess.hpp code into game_local.h and call it from there but that didnt work either.

I have set up a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/CppAndre/PreyRun) with all the code if some one is interested.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad english :/

Compiler output:

```
Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error C2371 'pr::InitPreySplitPipe': redefinition; different basic types
Error C2556 'int InitPreySplitPipe(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void pr::InitPreySplitPipe(void)'
```

## interprocess.hpp

```
namespace pr
{
(...)
void InitPreySplitPipe();
(...)
}
```

## interprocess.cpp

```
#include "interprocess.hpp"

namespace pr
{
(...)
    void InitPreySplitPipe()
    {
        pipe_preysplit = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\" PREYSPLIT_PIPE_NAME,PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS, 1, 256 * 1000, 0, 0, NULL);
        if (pipe_preysplit == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return;
        }

        std::memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));
        overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
        if (overlapped.hEvent == NULL)
        {
            pipe_preysplit = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
(...)
}
```

// Where the function shoud be called

## game_local.cpp

```
(...)
#include "../PreyRun/interprocess.hpp"
pr::InitPreySplitPipe();
(...)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the `c`-tag, or do you just find the tag aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: One way to get this error is to have the call at global scope, outside of any functions. Another is to have a circular include, where two .hpp files try to include each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In game_local.cpp:

```
// PreyRun BEGIN
#include "../PreyRun/interprocess.hpp"
pr::InitPreySplitPipe();
// PreyRun END
```

You are not calling the function from within anything, so the compiler thinks it's a new function declaration. Thus the type `int` is assumed, of which the overloaded function `int pr:InitPreySplitPipe()` conflicts with your `void pr::InitPreySplitPipe()`. This explains all 3 error messages.

Comment: @AMS You need to move it inside a function, like `main()`. If you don't want it in `main()`, then as part of some other function. You can't just have dangling function calls in the middle of nowhere. That's not how code works. How would the program know when and why to call it? If you're really that confused, I suggest reading basic coding tutorials.